# How can I UPDATE date using textarea

Tags: php, mysql

Need some help here. I am trying to update my date in my database using textarea. At first, I get the date from my database and post it in the textarea. But now I am trying to change the date by editing the date in the text area.

Here is my query.

```
$sql=mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE tblevent SET title='".$_POST['title']."' , 
eventdate='".$_POST['datee']."' body='".$_POST['body']."' , 
timestart='".$_POST['begtime']."' , timeend='".$_POST['endtime']."' WHERE 
eventid='".$_POST['id']."'" ) or mysqli_error(die($con));
```

`eventdate='".$_POST['datee']."'` is always getting an error

> "Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string"

here is my textarea

```
<?php echo "Date: <textarea name='datee' rows=1 cols=25>".$rows['eventdate']."</textarea>"; ?>
```

Comment: Textarea for `date`. I mean Why ?

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: As addition to Quentin: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: I suggest looking into the datepicker plug-in provided by JQuery UI. http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ It's easy to implement and looks fancy. The textarea for a single item is not what a textarea is ment for.

Comment: We are have this as an activity in our school and I am just a beginner in programming. we have to get the date from the data base and let it be automatically editable so I just input it in the textarea. any advice on where can I best put the date?

Comment: you are missing a comma after $_POST['datee']

Comment: If you're not going to use the JQuery Plug-in, which i assume you're not.. If you're using HTML5 i'd suggest: `<input type="date" /> `otherwise `<input type="text" />`

Comment: still having a problem in my query sir. I keep on having this error in updating my date in the database Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string

Comment: Please post more of your code, where is `$rows` populated?

Comment: $sql=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tblevent WHERE eventid='$id'");

$rows=mysqli_fetch_array($sql);

here it is sir

Answer (score 2):

You have missed a comma in this line

```
eventdate='".$_POST['datee']."' body='".$_POST['body']."'
```

it should be,

`eventdate='".$_POST['datee']."', body='".$_POST['body']."'`

Furthermore its better to use [**mysql_escape_string()**](https://www.php.net/mysql_escape_string) for each user input to avoid sql injection, rather than directly concatenating POST variables to SQL query string.